# Как реализовать сайт без скролла?

Tags: javascript, html, css

подскажите пожалуйста, как реализовать принцип этого сайта http://www.matthieutourdes.com/? Где переход на другие элементы страницы осуществляется без скролла, а по клике на ссылку.

Comment: То есть вам нужно убрать скролл?

Comment: Если так, то находится по первой же ссылке в поисковике: http://htmlbook.ru/faq/kak-ubrat-polosy-prokrutki

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Это [SPA](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9E%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5) сайт - страница полностью "рисуется" js скриптами

Comment: Спасибо, а где можно посмотреть на такую реализацию? Меня сильно заинтересовал такой способ создания сайтов

Comment: @eXamp1e, https://www.google.com/search?q=js+frameworks+supporting+spa&oq=js+frameworks+supporting+spa